# Django save blank value

Tags: python, django, database, python-3.x, model

I have a number of unknown values in a df, where the cells are filled with the chars '---'

I would like to tell Django that, if it finds something that is not a number of any kind (int / decimal / floating point) to leave the value of that field blank. I also want the default to be blank, but it does not seem to allow this either.

My model looks like this:

```
    value = models.FloatField(
    # default=blank,
    null=True,
    validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
)
```

My view calls a function like this:

```
    if (value == "---"):
        value = None

    MyModel(
        value=value,
    ).save()
```

My form looks like this:
from django import forms

from .models import WeatherStatistics

```
class WeatherStatisticsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WeatherStatistics
        fields = [
        "value",
        ]
```

How can I post a blank value to the db?

Comment: you get an error? what's not working?

Comment: I get this error: NOT NULL constraint failed: weatherstats_weatherstatistics.value

Comment: strange, this should not give you NOT NULL constraint error. are you sure you've run all makemigrations and migrations? Note that when validating your form, you don't allow for blank (because you don't set blank=True) and you'll hit the validation error that value should be >=0 as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove [**`MinValueValidator`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) if you want to save ***None*** value in db.

> **class MinValueValidator(min_value, message=None)**
>
> *Raises a ValidationError with a code of 'min_value' if value is less
>   than min_value*.

```
In [1]: a = None

In [2]: a < 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-29fc65191789> in <module>()
----> 1 a < 0

TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

Comment: true, but that's only produced at validation, not when saving to the db. He should still be able to do `MyModel(
        value=None,
    ).save()`